# how to mix my java code inside my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Ive spent the last nine hours trying to learn javascript and some jquery functions. All to achieve "what i thought to be" a simple modification in HTML file for my android app.

What i want to do is to give each letter in my HTML file a color. I already achieved this when reading from a textfile to a textView using spannableString. But using javascript gives some formating problems. My code will explain it better:

```
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
                //cSsO stores the color schema. Give a letter and return its color
                cSsO = new ColorizeSchemeClassObject(0);
                //Run a script that give color to each letter.
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "+
                        "for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) " +
                        "{var regExp = new RegExp('"+alphabet[0]+"', 'g');" +
                        "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regExp, " +
                        "'<font  color=\""+cSsO.ReturnCharColor(alphabet[0])+"\">"+alphabet[5]+"</font>');};"+
                        "})()");
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");
```

This code works, however there are some things i need to change and add to finally finish this.. I need to add the "(?![^<>]*>))" expression to my regExp search, so it doesnt mess up the HTML (i know this is not bulletproof but its enough for what i want), in normal javascript that i dont have to format to fit the loadUrl string i just write

```
var re = new RegExp( "(" + alphabet[0] + "(?![^<>]*>))", 'g' );
```

but i just cant seem to figure out how to incorporate that with the first code snippet (ive tried millions of way with ',",\, and + without success.

And my second quest, how can i use the var 'i' from the forloop inside my  alphabet array. E.g. alphabet['i'].

I appreciate all help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call native java code from javascript, use JavaScriptInterface of android.

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

Declare the class JavaScriptInterface:

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
        this.activity = activiy;
    }

    public void myNativeMethod(){
        // Do something
    }
}

You can call myNativeMethod() method of java like below from HTML/JS

<HTML>
onclick="window.JSInterface.myNativeMethod();"
</HTML>
```

For more details check,
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Thanks for you input. However, i have not clue how to incorporate that to my situation.

Comment: @user3711421 This is the only way in android to call java code from Webview's Javascript. Try and let me know about this.

Comment: But i am calling it correctly in my first code example. I.e. i load the script inside the webView directly, it does work. Its just that i need help with some formating to mix the java variable and the javascript variables.

Comment: I think some confusion is here, as per your question ***how to mix my java code inside my javascript code ?*** I thought you need to call (Mix) native java code function from javascript of Webview's HTML. So solution is ***addJavascriptInterface*** for webview. What you mean by ***MIX*** here ?

Comment: what i mean by mix is for example. you see my alphabet[0], it is declared in my java code (above the loadUrl), my for loop is declared in my javascript code. The red code is javascript while the other code is java code. i want to use my alphabet[0] but instead of taking [0] i want to take the forloops 'i' variable. Something like this alphabet[i].

Comment: Okay.So basically you need alphabet[] array in JS.
Solution (1) Simply declare alphabet[] array in JS code.
Solution (2) If you want to access it (through jsinterface) from JAVA code then write function like getter which returns you that array in JS.

Comment: Reversed actually, i want the alphabet[] i java, i only want the iterator 'i' inside the ['i']. The i is from the js for loop. I tried breaking the code like alphabet['i'], alphabet[i], alphabet['+i+'], and so on... I will try to do it as you proposed though. I mean i could just declare two js []: Alphabet and CharColors, ala "var CharColor = '"+cSsO.getColorArray()+"';" and "var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopq'.split('');" Than just work with them, because js var can use the iterator. However, i would like to know the syntax to mix it, bc i think its just some '+"or/ that is needed.